# On a recursive sequence (exercise 8.9 Apostol)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, self-learning

The exercise states: show convergence of the sequence ${a_n}$ knowing that:

$$|a_n| \le 2, \ \ \ |a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}| \le \frac{1}{8}|a_{n+1}^2 - a_{n}^2|.$$

The solution states:

$$|a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}| \le \frac{1}{8}|a_{n+1}^2 - a_{n}^2| = \frac{1}{8}|a_{n+1} - a_{n}||a_{n+1} + a_{n}| \le \frac{1}{2}|a_{n+1} - a_{n}| $$

since $|a_n| \le 2$ we know that $|a_{n+1} - a_{n}| \le (\frac{1}{2})^{n-1}$ ...

This last step is not very clear to me, could somebody explain it to me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: From $\lvert a_{n+2} - a_{n+1}\rvert \leqslant \frac{1}{2}\lvert a_{n+1} - a_n\rvert$, you obtain $\lvert a_{n+2} - a_{n+1}\rvert \leqslant \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\lvert a_1 - a_0\rvert$. What then remains is to see $\lvert a_1 - a_0\rvert \leqslant 4$.

Comment: An useful identity is $|x-y|\leq|x|+|y|$.

Comment: We have $|a_1 - a_0| \leq |a_1| + |a_0| \leq 4$. Prove by induction that $|a_{n+1} - a_n| \leq 4(1/2)^{n} = (1/2)^{n-2}$. This will be enough to carry on with the proof, though to be honest, I don't immediately see why $(1/2)^{n-1}$ works. In any case, you don't need it.

Comment: Okay, the sequnce probably starts at $1$, not zero. Prove that $|a_3 - a_2| \leq 1/2$ using $|a_1|, |a_2| \leq 2$, and then prove the inequality by induction. The book's $(1/2)^{n-1}$ works.

Comment: @Monolite, I am adding one more step for your in Daniel Fischer's answer.  $\lvert a_{n+2} - a_{n+1}\rvert \leqslant \frac{1}{2}\lvert a_{n+1} - a_n\rvert \leqslant \frac{1}{4}\lvert a_{n} - a_{n-1}\rvert...$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $-2\leq a_n\leq 2$

$$|a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}| \le \frac{1}{8}|a_{n+1}^2 - a_{n}^2| = \frac{1}{8}|a_{n+1} - a_{n}||a_{n+1} + a_{n}| \leq \frac{1}{8}|a_{n+1} - a_{n}||4|= \frac{1}{2}|a_{n+1} - a_{n}| $$

Next, call $b_n=a_{n+1}-a_n$ and rewrite the above.